# Consider an array n of integers A=[a1,a2,a3......an]. Find and print the total number of pairs such that ai*aj <= max(ai,ai+1,.....aj) where i < j

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

Can anyone please help me with the above question.
We have to find combination of elements in the array (a1,a2),(a1,a3),(a1,a4).... so on, and pick those combinations which satisfies the condition (ai*aj) <= max(A) where A is the array and return the number of combinations possible.

Example : input array A = [1,1,2,4,2] and it returns 8 as the combinations are :
(1,1),(1,2),(1,4),(1,2),(1,2),(1,4),(1,2),(2,2).

It's easy to solve this using nested for loops but that would be very time consuming.(O(n^2)).

## Naive algorithm:

```
array = [1,1,2,4,2]
result = []
for i in range(len(array)):
   for j in range(len(array)):
       if array[i] * array[j] <= max(array):
           if (array[j],array[i]) not in result:
               result.append((array[i],array[j]))
print(len(result))
```

What should be the approach when we encounter such problems ?

Comment: Constraints are: 1 <= n <= 5x10^5 and 1<=ai<=10^9 . So the complexity must be good. I tried the n^2 algorithm but it dint even passed a single test case.

Comment: `ai*aj <= max(ai,ai+1,…aj)` is not the same as `(ai*aj) <= max(A)` - which one is it?

Comment: 1 step would be to not calculate for duplicates more than once and instead count the number of times the duplicate appeared (if it met the criteria)

Comment: @Dukeling, Please consider this ai*aj <= max(ai,ai+1,…aj) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about sorting the array, then iterating up: for each element, `e`, binary search the closest element to `floor(max(A) / e)` that's lower than or equal to `e`. Add the number of elements to the left of that index. (If there are many duplicates, hash their count, present only two of them in the sorted array, and use prefix sums to return the correct number of items to the left of any index.)

```
1 1 2 4 2

1 1 2 2 4
0
  1
    2
      3
        2
```

Answer (score 1):

What I understand reading your problem description is that you want to find the total count of pairs whose multiplication is less than the maximum element in the range between these pairs i.e. `ai*aj <= max(ai,ai+1,…aj)`.

The naive approach suggested by [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6567275/thomas) is easy to understand but it is still of time complexity of `O(n^2))`. We can optimize this to reduce the time complexity to `O(n*log^2n)`. Lets discuss about it in details.

At first, from each index- i, we can find out the range say `{l, r}` in which element at index- i will be greater than or equal to all the elements from `l` to `i` , as well as it is greater than all elements ranges from `i + 1` to `r`. This can be easily calculated in O(n) time complexity using the idea of [histogram data-structure](https://bishalg.blogspot.com/2018/09/hackerrank-find-maximum-index-product.html).

Now, lets for each index-i, we find out such range `{l, r}`, and if we want to traverse over minimum length out of two ranges i.e. `min( i - l, r - i )` then overall we will traverse `n*logn` indices for overall array. While traversing over small length range, if we encounter some element say `x`, then we somehow have to find out how many elements exists in other range such that values are less than `ai / x`. This can be solved using offline processing with [Fenwick Tree data-structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree) in O(logn) time complexity for each query. Hence, we can solve above problem with overall complexity of `O(n log^2 n)` time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

> It's easy to solve this using nested for loops but that would be very time consuming.(O(n^2)).

since `where i < j` we can cut this in half:

```
for i in range(len(array)):
  for j in range(i+1, len(array)):
    ...
```

Now let's get rid of this part `if (array[j],array[i]) not in result:` as it does not reflect your results: `(1,1),(1,2),(1,4),(1,2),(1,2),(1,4),(1,2),(2,2)` here you have dupes.

The next expensive step we can get rid of is `max(array)` wich is not only wrong *(`max(ai,ai+1,…aj)` translates to `max(array[i:j])`)* but has to iterate over a whole section of the array in each iteration. Since the Array doesn't change, the only thing that may change this maximum is `array[j]`, the new value you're processing.

Let's store that in a variable:

```
array = [1,1,2,4,2]
result = []

for i in range(len(array)):
  maxValue = array[i]
  for j in range(i+1, len(array)):
    if array[j] > maxValue:
      maxValue = array[j]
    if array[i] * array[j] <= maxValue:
      result.append((array[i], array[j]))

print(len(result))
```

Still a naive algorithm, but imo we've made some improvements.

Another thing we could make is not only store the `maxValue`, but also a `pivot = maxValue / array[i]` and therefore replace the multiplication by a simple comparison `if array[j] <= pivot:`. Doing this under the assumption that the multiplication would have been called way more often than the `maxValue` and therefore the `pivot` changes.

But since I'm not very experienced in python, I'm not sure wether this would make any difference in python or wether I'm on the road to pointless micro-optimizations with this.